# How can I group by a datetime column with timezone?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'StartDate':['2020-01-01 00:00:00-04:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00-04:00', '2020-01-01 01:55:00-04:00', '2020-01-02 02:00:00-02:00', '2020-01-02 02:00:00-04:00'],
        'Weight':[100, 110, 120, 125, 155]
    }
)
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])

df
```

[image: df1]

I want to group the data ***by the hour*** and sum up the Weight column. So, the end result would be a df with 3 rows: current index 0, current indexes 1&2, current indexes 3&4.

I came across the [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) function and I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='StartDate', freq='H')).sum()
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
> PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can someone provide a solution?

Thanks

Comment: What time format is this：2020-01-01 00:00:00-04:00

Comment: I'm getting data from an API and that's exactly how the data is provided to me. It gets imported as an object/string. The format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I don't know what that last bit is, for example `-04:00`. Should I first trim that last part off and then try converting to a `datetime` object?

Comment: The last bit is a timezone relative to UTC (UTC minus 4 hours in this case)

Comment: Maybe the timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert to datetime, taking into account the timezones:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], utc=True)

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='StartDate', freq='H')).sum()
```

Output:

```
                           Weight
StartDate                        
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00     100
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00     230
2020-01-01 06:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 07:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 08:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 09:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 10:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 11:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 12:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 13:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 14:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 15:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 16:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 17:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 18:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 19:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 20:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 21:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 22:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-01 23:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 01:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 02:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 03:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 04:00:00+00:00     125
2020-01-02 05:00:00+00:00       0
2020-01-02 06:00:00+00:00     155
```

##### without "blanks"

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], utc=True).dt.floor('h'))['Weight'].sum()

StartDate
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    100
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00    230
2020-01-02 04:00:00+00:00    125
2020-01-02 06:00:00+00:00    155
Name: Weight, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was going to write, "Didn't I do that?" and then I noticed the utc=True argument. That's New York time in UTC. Thanks! Is there a way to not include the blanks because my actual df is quite large?

Comment: Yes, see the edit

Comment: @Corralien yes and they are not grouped together, no?

Comment: NB. If you really wanted to ignore the timezones (which IMO is incorrect), you would need to remove it from the string before converting to datetime

Comment: Normally, when I add in `as_index=False` in the groupby, the grouped column doesn't become the index. In this case, it's getting removed altogether and I'm left with just the Weight column. `df = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], utc=True).dt.floor('h'), as_index=False)['Weight'].sum()`  https://i.imgur.com/dz0IlQt.png

Comment: Note that this solution probably produces correct results only for 'H' (hourly) groupings. As soon as you go to day, week or month, the removed timezone information will skew the results.